# Android FPS increases when touching view and decreases when not touched

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I know this is a really odd problem. But has happened both on my Nexus S and Galaxy Tab.

When i drag on the view FPS increases to MAX FPS however if I don't it'll start fluctuating from 45-60. I've already tried tested simulations and it isn't the batching. I am using Open GL and there are no memory leaks. Any ideas?

This happens on all projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Jelly Bean? They added a new feature, as part of Project Butter, that might explain this.

> Jelly Bean has more reactive and uniform touch responses, and makes
>   your device even more responsive by boosting your device's CPU
>   instantly when you touch the screen, and turns it down when you don't
>   need it to improve battery life.

http://www.android.com/about/jelly-bean/

Comment: oh thanks, that's probably it. Is there anyway I can disable it?

Comment: Not that I could tell. But why would you want to disable this?